# Collection View Storing Button Pressed Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view where it needs to store which button is pressed. This is like a quiz where they have options A, B, C, D. The problem is that it will select the item with this code:

```
extension QuestionCell {
func configure(with model: Question) {
    factLabel.text = model.fact
    questionLabel.text = model.question
    revenueLabel.text = model.revenue
    let views = answersStack.arrangedSubviews
    for view in views {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    for (id, answer) in model.answers {
        print(index)
        let answerLabel = UILabel()
        answerLabel.text = answer

        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerLabel)

        let answerButton = UIButton()
       answerButton.tag = index
        let imageNormal = UIImage(named: "circle_empty")
        answerButton.setImage(imageNormal, for: .normal)
        let imageSelected = UIImage(named: "circle_filled")
        answerButton.setImage(imageSelected, for: .selected)
        answerButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerButton)

    }
}
```

But then if you swipe a couple times and then come back to this question the image will be white again. How can I fix this problem. Also I attached how the screen looks.

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0lYC.png)

~ Thanks

Comment: Well if you're running this loop every time you redraw the view for a new question then you're remaking new answer buttons every time with the line  `let answerButton = UIButton()`. You need a way to keep track of which answer was selected when you build the view. I would suggest making answer a custom class instead of a String, and your new Answer class could have a property called text and one called wasSelected that keeps track of which one the user picked. I could write out more in a full answer if you're new to coding and want it spelled out more.

Comment: @KyleSomers yeah full answer would be great, cause it is a little confusing right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with an Answer class like this. In case you're new to classes, I should point out that you *won't* want to write this code inside another class definition (like your ViewController class.)

```
class Answer{
    var wasSelected = false
    var text : String

    init(text : String) {
        self.text = text
    }

}
class ButtonWithAnswer : UIButton{
    var answer : Answer?
}
```

But now your model.answers will look like this, and will be of type `[String : Answer]`:

```
model.answers = ["id1" : Answer(text : "answer 1"), "id2" : Answer(text: "answer 2"), "id3":Answer(text: "answer 3")]
```

The idea is that instead of having model.answers contain strings, they contain a new custom type that we made up called Answer that can keep track of the text for the answer (which is a property called text of type String) as well as whether or not it was selected (which is a property called wasSelected of type Bool). Your for loop will now look like this:

```
for (id, answer) in model.answers {
    let answerLabel = UILabel()
    answerLabel.text = answer.text //this comes from our new class definition

    answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerLabel)
    //Change this to our new custom button subclass
    let answerButton = ButtonWithAnswer()
    //this line straight up won't work since you got rid of index
    //answerButton.tag = index

    //use this instead
    answerButton.answer = answer
    let imageNormal = UIImage(named: "circle_empty")
    answerButton.setImage(imageNormal, for: .normal)
    let imageSelected = UIImage(named: "circle_filled")
    answerButton.setImage(imageSelected, for: .selected)

    //make it so that any answers that were previously selected are now selected when the view reloads
    answerButton.isSelected = answer.wasSelected


    answerButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerButton)


}
```

There's one last piece of this. We need to make sure that we make our answer.wasSelected equal to true when we tap the button that corresponds with that answer. So in answerPressed we should do something like this.

```
func answerPressed(_ sender : UIButton){
    let answerForButton = (sender as! ButtonWithAnswer).answer!
    answerForButton.wasSelected = true


}
```

That should about cover it. If this looks like something totally new then you should look up tutorials on classes, objects, and init methods in Swift before you dive in or ask a programmer for help in person. But I explained it about as well as I can without actually being there in person to give you a complete walkthrough.

Comment: What do a do with the model.answers bit? And also I am getting three errors : Value of  type String has no member "text"

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand classes and objects (and that's fine, we were all new at some point), but if that's the case then my answer is going to hurt you more than help you at this point by making you more confused. Like I said at the bottom of my answer, go look at tutorials on those subjects and come back when my code makes sense. Your question doesn't have an answer where you can just add 2 lines of code. You need to go learn stuff. To answer your question, the issue is that model.answers is currently an array of String and you'll want to instead have an array of Answer

Comment: I did this, but the problem is that it cannot call model because it is not a global variable. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I can't see your code so I don't know how you're defining things. Wherever you have model.answers defined, you need to change it so that you're adding Answer objects to it, not Strings. What does the line of code look like where you add stuff to your model.answers array?

Comment: No. I meant that I updated my question with the right code. Would you be able to solve my question, with model not being global?

Comment: The thing is that I can't use your model.answers bit. I am using a database, so to connect it, my answers struct looks like this -- let answers: [String: String]. Do you have some code that would work for this?

Comment: @John Okay, so now model.answers is a dictionary instead of an array, I dig. That changes a few things and I updated my answer accordingly. I did use another custom subclass (ButtonWithAnswer), and I'm skeptical as to whether or not you understand classes and objects, so just to be super clear: I literally teach students to make iOS apps for a living. It is my job. If you don't learn how classes, subclasses, and objects work in Swift, you will hit a brick wall and you are right now. If my code doesn't make sense at least 95%, go learn classes. Otherwise you'll implement it wrong and get errors

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-an-introduction-to-classes-and-structures--cms-23197